# links overlapping one another

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

The links on my site (About, Gallery and Contact) overlap when you hover over them. When you have the mouse midway on the About tab the Gallery tab highlights and likewise when you have the mouse midway on the Gallery tab the Contact tab highlights. The same problem happen from the bottom tab working up.

http://www.redechoevents.co.uk/

```
/*Logo
------------------------------------------------------------ */ 
#logo-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 217px;
    height: 628px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#about {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 89px;
    width: 336px;
}

span.title-link {
    font-size: 6.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 93px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

span.title-link a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.title-link a:hover {
    color: #E91F4C;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#about-red {
    left: -104px;
    width: 545px;
}

#logo-red {
    height: 93px;
    width: 209px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 336px;
}   

/*Echo
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#gallery {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 92px;
    width: 434px;
}   

#gallery-echo {
    left: -202px;
    width: 714px;
}

#logo-echo {
    height: 93px;
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 434px;
}   

/*Events
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#contact-events {
    left: -216px;
    width: 862px;
}   

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 92px;
    width: 448px;
}   

#logo-events {
    height: 93px;
    width: 414px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 448px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And adjust the `width` for `#about-red`, `#gallery-echo` and `#contact-events` to at least `900px`, so you dont get a horizontal scroll bar.

```
#about-red,
#gallery-echo,
#contact-events {
    width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you test it on different operating systems since the font can have different width, maybe you will need more than 900px...